# Using .htaccess to redirect by domain, either in the URL or in HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am hosting several domains on the same apache server and I want to set them all up so that /home is unique to each domain. (suppose I have 3 domains example.com example1.com and example2.com) I have setup my file structure like this...

```
 /www/htdocs/domain/example
 /www/htdocs/domain/example1
 /www/htdocs/domain/example2

 http://example.com/home/   ==>  .../domain/example/
 http://example1.com/home/  ==>  .../domain/example1/
 http://example2.com/home/  ==>  .../domain/example2/
```

So I have an htaccess rule like this

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%1/$1 [L]
```

This works perfectly. But I want to extend it to include www.example.com So I add this rule.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%2/$1 [L]
```

That works great, and is generally how I have been building my .htaccess file. It is growing quite unweildy and I need to rethink my approach. So I am trying to concatenate the above two rules into a single block. Here is what I have but it isn't working...

```
 RewriteCond ^home/
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.(.+)\.(.+)$ [OR]
 RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%2/$1 [L]
```

Additionally and separately I would like a rule that would cause the following URL to return error 404.

```
http://example1.com/domain/example/logo.jpg
```

Comment: I'm confused at what is required to be done here... Could you please explain what do you want to be done a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. At least the first part. I am still looking for an answer to the second part.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.(.+)\.(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%1/$1 [L]
```